# Quando usar o método http Patch?

Tags: http, restful, patch

Fiz algumas pesquisas sobre o método **PATCH**, e vi que ele faz modificações parciais, porém não entendi na prática quando usá-lo e qual a sua diferença para o **PUT**.

Estou procurando um exemplo prático de como/quando e por que usar o método **PATCH** já que em vários lugares possui apenas uma definição, achei um material bem interessante talvez eu mesmo responda minha dúvida.

Fonte: http://williamdurand.fr/2014/02/14/please-do-not-patch-like-an-idiot/

Comment: Aliás, a pergunta é duplicata, mas eu acho que aquela lá merece respostas mais aprofundadas.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`PUT` quando modificar todos os atributos.
`PATCH` quando modificar um ou alguns atributos, mas não todos.

Mais informações: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24241893/rest-api-patch-or-put